# Youtube Push Notifications not working

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I recently started working with YouTube Push Notifications via PubSubHubbub.

I used https://pubsubhubbub.appspot.com/subscribe to subscribe to the topic https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UC4cqnixbcB71Aynmukw52kA

Notice that the URL is different from the one given on the official Youtube Documentation, because that URL unfortunately does not work and only returns a 403 code with "Restricted topic" ( I cant link the issue unfortunately, because I can only include 2 links )

When I check the status of the subscription it says "State: verified", but even when a new video us uploaded, there is no attempt to notify my server and my Server did not receive any POST requests on the webhook URL, other than my test requests.

It seems like maybe the topic URL is not the right one to use, but neither is the URL specified on the official Documentation.

Did anyone experience similar issues or knows why YouTube is not pushing any notification?

Comment: This has been opened in this [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35175433). Check for updates.